# Does spark head function returns smallest value when data is sorted in ascending order

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have an ordered dataset, now if I apply a filter on the dataset and take the first element like this

```
dataset.sort($"data_column".asc).filter(_.data_column > 60).first()
```

Will spark return the smallest value which is less than 60?
I am concerned because my dataset is huge and expected to have more than 500 partitions so does the `first()` functions respect the data sort order after applying the filter?

Comment: if you filter, sort and then do first, that would maintain the order, but just filter i dont think maintains the order. reference : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16207

Comment: That's is my assumption too, I was hoping to avoid the sort though. Off-topic, I am a TUM student too :D, posting this comment from the RechnerHallen

Comment: haha thats a good coincidence! :D